# Socket event occurs twice

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets

I am working on multiroom chat system in nodejs and socket.io.

Here is my server side script

```
socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {

    socket.username = data.name;
    // store the room name in the socket session for this client
    socket.room = data.room;
    // add the client's username to the global list
    usernames[data.name] = data.name;
    // send client to room
    socket.join(data.room);

    // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('updatechat',data.name, data);
});
```

And the client side

```
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    var html = '<div class="media">'+ 
                '<div class="media-left"> '+
                   '<a href="#"> '+
                      '<img class="media-object img-circle" data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64" '+
                       'src="assets/images/profile/'+data.img+'" data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">'+
                          '</a>'+
                           '</div>'+ 
                           '<div class="media-body">'+
                            '<h4 class="media-heading">'+data.name+'</h4> <p>'+data.message+'</p><a class="chat-time">'+
                             '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>'+moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')+'</a></div>'+ 
                          '</div>';                   

     $("#dash_threads").html(html); });
```

Whenever trigger this event it occurs twice. I had checked all the possible solutions but none of that worked. Can anyone guide me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is due to two reasons.

1) Socket connection restart after idle connection
2) Include the socket file twice.

You can solve it by adding some boolean value to it check for first time connection occured or not, if it is the first time add the event listeners to the socket.

```
client.isFirstTime = false;
socket.on('connect',function(){
 if (!client.isFirstTime){
      // add event listeners
 }
});
```